# Angular accordion - multiple opened groups

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, accordion

is it possible to open more groups at the same time.
Now, if I click on some group and expand it, all others are getting collapsed.
I want to see more expanded groups at the same time.

```
   <accordion>
        <accordion-group heading="{{condition.name}}" ng-repeat="condition in conditions" is-open="condition.isOpen" data-ng-click="setCategoryStatus(condition)">
            <li ng-repeat="item in condition.items">
                    <div>{{item.description}}</div>
            </li>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

Controller:

```
      $scope.setCategoryStatus = function (category) {
          var index = $scope.conditions.indexOf(category);
          $scope.conditions[index].isOpen = !$scope.conditions[index].isOpen;
      };
```

Data:

```
    [
{
    "name": "First",
    "isOpen":true,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "Some desc",

        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "Some desc  2",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Second",
    "isOpen":true,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "Some desc",

        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "Some desc  2",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#accordion), use the `close-others` attribute, which can be true or false:

```
<accordion close-others="false">
    <accordion-group heading="{{condition.name}}" ng-repeat="condition in conditions" is-open="condition.isOpen" data-ng-click="setCategoryStatus(condition)">
        <li ng-repeat="item in condition.items">
                <div>{{item.description}}</div>
        </li>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```